# How to return data from another activity, back button only way to return from launced activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an lg g-slate that has two rear cameras to take stereoscopic (3D) pictures/video.  In my app I am trying to call the 3D video recorder application that came preinstalled on the device.  I was able to successfully start the app with the following:

```
    Intent i;
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    try {
        i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.lge.stereo.camcorder");
        if (i == null)
            throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
```

After recording a video with the app there is no way to return from the app besides using the back button.  So, in onActivityResult() the result code is RESULT_CANCELLED and there is no way for me to get any data returned from the intent.  I would like to get the Uri of the file where the video was saved but I am not sure how I would be able to do this since using the back button is the only way to return from the app.

I have used the following code before to record 2D video:

```
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);
```

After recording a video a dialog popups where you can select "Ok" to return to your application and get the file URI in onActivityResult.

Is there any way to launch the 3D video recorder so that I can get a result back?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]**Open camera app within your app only** on a custom layout. Where you can have two buttons for save and discard video. As user press to save video save it on a predefined location and you will get to know the path of video as you have already defined it yourself and when user press cancel video discard the location and cancel video or just override back button functionality.

for e.g.

Inside your onCreate() method , get instance of camera

```
private Camera myCamera;
// Get Camera for preview
myCamera = getCameraInstance();


private Camera getCameraInstance() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            // attempt to get a Camera instance
            c = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        // returns null if camera is unavailable
        return c;
    }
```

now create Surface view for camera

```
         private MyCameraSurfaceView myCameraSurfaceView;

        myCameraSurfaceView = new MyCameraSurfaceView(this, myCamera);
        FrameLayout myCameraPreview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
        myCameraPreview.addView(myCameraSurfaceView);

        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(myButtonOnClickListener);

        flashOff = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.flashoff);
        flashTorch = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.flashtorch);
```

and create your layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/videoview"
            android:layout_width="720px"
            android:layout_height="480px" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mybutton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="REC"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/flashoff"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="OFF"
                    android:textSize="8dp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/flashtorch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Torch"
                    android:textSize="8dp" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <Button
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_next"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="NEXT"
                android:textSize="12dp" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I would rather try to find a way to use the existing 3D recording app than create one from scratch.  I need to record 3D video using both the rear cameras.  The existing app has several options available such as setting the 3D mode (anaglyph, mixed, or side-by-side) and also depth control.  Creating an application with the same functionality would be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a suitable solution. I get the current time in milliseconds before calling startActivityForResult, then I get the current time in onActivityResult. I know the directory the 3D recorder saves the videos so I iterate through the files in the directory and check the last modified times of each file. If the last modified time is between the start and end times of using the 3D recorder app I know that this was the video that was recorded.